# How is IRQ serviced in Linux when pre-emption is disabled?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, interrupt-handling

I've read in some books that for servicing an interrupt the data around CPU is stored into stack and the current process in preempted. Now, If the kernel is non-preemptive or preemption is disabled. How does preemption happen and ISR() serviced ?

Can somebody explain me this or point me to some source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there are different types of *pre-emptions*, a user process or a kernel context on behalf of user-space.

User-space may always pre-empt.  There are various situations and configurations where the kernel code may block this pre-emption.

The ISR is always serviced (unless IRQs are masked; very rare and short).  A kernel routine (like already running a process swap) may disable kernel/user space per-emption until it is finished its business.  [The source](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/kernel/entry-armv.S#n202) is usually in assembler and may depend on kernel options.  When the kernel context resumes pre-emption, then a context switch may occur.

See the diagram below....

[image]

The *blue* part is where the kernel keeps doing an `sbrk()` for task 2.  If pre-emption wasn't disabled, it would go to task 1 immediately.  It may need to atomically get some memory page for that task.  Usually this is short.  When it re-ables the pre-emption, we will notice that an IRQ has occurred and data is ready for the *task 1* and then a context switch will occur.  The *task 2* will still be waiting for the `sbrk()` to finish.

There are actually two task context (kernel stacks) for each of *task 1* and *task 2*; but it is running the same kernel code and the higher kernel memory space all looks the same (I put this all under the heading 'kernel').  The user space is completely different (virtual memory).  My UML is probably really mixed up.  I don't have some Dia sequence view.

Comment: The 'kernel context' happens on an `svc` or `syscall`; this is work that the kernel does for user space.  Usually this work can be pre-empted.  Option like 'server work load', 'low-latency desktop', etc influence this decision.  Also known as *real-time* patches (or at least originating there).  For server workload configurations, the kernel always finishes its business for that task.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as a "non-preempt*ive* Linux kernel". User space tasks can always be pre-empted.

Perhaps you mean "non-preempt*ible*". A non-preemptible kernel is one where kernel code cannot be pre-empted in the sense that it cannot be suspended in order to allow another process or thread to run. However, it's possible that interrupt handlers can still run; there's just a limit to what they are allowed to do.

In any case, if an interrupt request cannot be serviced immediately, it remains pending until it *is* serviced.